# How to click 'Submit' button using a specific tag with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Page source code below:

```
<button class="ui-button-primary ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default 
ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="submit" data-
qa="sidebar.find.submit.button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">Find</span></button>
```

How do I click this button with Selenium Webdriver and is it possible to click it using the qa=sidebar.find.submit.button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use a *CSS selector*:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[data-qa="sidebar.find.submit.button"]')
```

Comment: Is there another way to select this button?  This way did not work for some reason.  I got 'unable to locate element' error.

Comment: @david sorry, fixed the selector, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here you Go

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-qa='sidebar.find.submit.button']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

And in python, this way :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-qa='sidebar.find.submit.button']")).click();
```